# Complicated mySql query "Sibling" Categories of a product

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complpicated query for a shopping cart
if a customer puts in the cart a product, the system must show some "additional" categories of products based on a db field

each product has a category and some "cross selling" (related) categories
each product has a parent category and "siblings" in the same category

If a user adds a product in the cart, the cart should show its "cross selling" categories (something like "you may be interested in...")

but each product category in the cart must remove its "sibling" (in the same parent category) if they are "cross selling categories" of another product in the cart...

a "sibling" can be "cross selling" for its related sibling

let me explain in more simple terms:

a user buys a flight to London 
the system must then suggest related categories such as "Tower of london tickets" as well as "harry potter kids ticket", "harry potter adult tickets", "harry potter family tickets"

if the user adds one of the "harry potter" tickets, the system must then exclude all "harry potters" that are in the same category, even if they are related to the flight the customer bought

database side, everything is around a single "categories" table and a list of products

category table is like this (simplified):

`category_id, parent_id, cross_selling` categories

`category_id is an integer.`
parent_id`is an integer.`
cross_selling` categories is a string: list of integers like (188, 189, 200)

Comment: and what is now the question?

Comment: I think he wants us to write his query

Comment: I would simply like to have hints on how to proceed, if it's possibile to write it as a single mySql query...

i find it complicated because the "cross_selling" are stored as string instead of integers

Comment: please make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: We can't just create a whole query for you. Try to make the query as far as you can, if you run against problems while doing that you can ask it here on SO. Otherwise it would be just a freelancing site with the emphasis on free :) People get paid to make such a query

Comment: ok , so just one simple answer, don't write the whole query: is this feasible in mySql or not in your opinion?

Comment: Yes. Entirely feasible.

Comment: if related categories were a one->many relationship I would be able tyo create the query, but having the related categories in a string makes it more complicated in my opinion...

Comment: um, so don't have them in a string

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to change how you store this information.
Your database structure makes this nearly impossible to do in pure sql which this should be in.

The proper structure would be to take out your cross_selling column and create a new table...

(product_cross_selling)
product_id, category_id

Given your example a product 1 would have
1, 188,
1,189,
1,200

Then you can simply have a query to lookup related items...

select item.* FROM products JOIN product_cross_selling ON item.category_id = category_id WHERE product_cross_selling.product_id = ?

Where ? is the id of the cart item that was added.

I hope this makes sense.